# How did the data fetching approaches change from NextJS pre-13.4 to v13.4+

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

The data fetching approaches that changed from NextJS pre-13.4 to v13.4+ seem very significant.

One area that has seen some serious overhaul is the data fetching.

Pre-v13.4 under `data fetching` in the NextJS docs, you saw functions like this:

- getStaticProps
- getStaticPaths
- Forms and Mutations
- getServerSideProps
- Incremental Static Regeneration
- Client-side Fetching
- SWR

Post v13.4, you see the `data fetching` split like this:

- On the server, with fetch
- On the server, with third-party libraries
- On the client, via a Route Handler
- On the client, with third-party libraries.

Along with more seeming emphasis on Server Actions as well for Forms.

Which seems like a departure from using various specialized calls to the API.  Also, generally speaking you saw a migration from using NextAPIRequest/Response to NextRequest/Response.

How / why did it change?  What is the overall approach/goals of the change? (This will be quite helpful in contextualizing the changes/migration/architecture pattern.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this question](https://(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423391/comparing-data-fetching-approaches-in-nextjs-conceptually-why-are-there-so-man)) to better help understand where we started pre-v13.4).

Then let’s talk about where v13.4 took us.

First of all, we switched from an app router scheme from a page router scheme and the introduction of ‘use client’ and server-based components   This is out of scope of the question but I mention it as these are probably the most obvious out-of-the box changes, and there are a few downstream implication from this.

When it come to data fetching in particular, there are probably four things that have significantly changed.

Now fetching data from APIs is a pretty fundamental concept so why should there be so much change from one version of NextJS to the …next? =). Here is why:

**First change:** (From Node to Native Web API Interfaces)
1/ (I really like this one).   NextJS switched most of the requests and responses from NextAPIRequest/NextAPIResponse to NextRequest/NextResponse.

Now, they obviously look similar and you may have seen them in Javascript as simply req/res (so no obvious change to you), and they play a similar role to each other but actually they are pretty different.  The  syntax you used to use to attach status messages etc are different for each, which is why there are breaking changes when you switch from pre-v13.4 to v13.4+.

NextAPIRequest/NextAPIResponse is derived from Node  http.IncomingMessage)/(http.ServerResponse).

NextRequest/NextResponse is derived from the native Request/Response (as in APIs you would normally look through on mdn web docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

So the first shift is moving from a node based system to a native web request system. I think that this is great because it makes developing with NextJS a matter of developing with:

- React
- some extra NextJS routing nuances
- using fundamental web interfaces that you would need anyway
- and thereby removing the need to use Node.

I consider this a good move, as it removes some technical overhead and represents a move closer “to the metal” so to speak.

The easy way that I grock this shift is that NextJS used to give you a node server for free, but now they give you serverless functions for free (and these serverless functions allow you to use native fetch and native Web API interfaces (Request/Response).

**Second Change:** (From lots of different data fetching functions with their own cache/refresh functionality to an overall cache/refresh Architecture so you can mix-and-match yourself).

So if you go back to these functions from pre-v13.4

- getStaticProps
- Incremental Static Regeneration
- getServerSideProps

These functions had special functionality and updating patterns.  For example, getStaticProps would make the function calls at build time and also have some opportunity to revalidate after a certain amount of time.

However, now, NextJS introduced a caching and revalidation architecture (mixed with automatic fetch memoizing) … so this functionality essentially happens for free.

For example, your fetch calls now get automatically cache-ed at build time by default unless you opt out.

> By default, Next.js will cache as much as possible to improve
> performance and reduce cost. This means routes are statically
> rendered and data requests are cached unless you opt out.

So this essentially eliminates the need for a standalone function that does that for you like getStaticProps.  Also, now with this cache architecture and now that data calls are memoized, you don’t even need to fetch data from a top level component and pass them down the component tree across a particular route (ie. From Layout, Page, to Parent Component, to Child component.). You can simply fetch them in the components — this simply removes the hassel of pushing things down the component tree and make things easier.  (Note this is within the Components and not in the Route Handlers which is not in the React Component tree.)

For further context, Next has very helpful diagrams of how caching works [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching).

**Third Change:** From all Client Components to A Mix of Client + Server Components (This piggy backs to NextJS's shift to using ‘use client’ Components and Server Components.)

Pre-v13.4, these functions (getStaticProps, getServerSideProps) get removed by NextJS from the client-side bundle (ie. NextJS will remove the code so that sensitive code isn’t downloaded to the client).  Vercel even provided a tool tool to see it happen in real-time: https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/

But Post-v13.4, you can write your own functions from a Server Component where it will run from the server which eliminates the need for this code elimination tooling.  If you need something that is meant to be server only, it can still be passed to client only code via passing it as a parameter or as child to the client component.

Also, of note, by using a npm package like server-only you can also define certain standalone javascript functions to NOT be able to be imported into the use-client code.  Which helps preventing mistakenly sending server only code to the client.  And creates another avenue for safe server-side only function calls.

**Fourth Change:** (RPC … are you with me?) 
Forms and Mutation, Server Actions.

In v13.4, NextJS introduced Server Actions (not to be confused with Server Components.)

This is somewhat akin to a RPC where you are calling from client component to the server component.  Read, instead of doing a fetch to your route handler/API, you are doing something akin to an Remote Procedure Call that does this for you (so you're not doing a normal HTTP call and as a bonus, you don't even need Javascript to be enabled on the client side for this to work.)

Generally you would use these server actions to take the input in a form and then from your server action upload this input to your database — and it comes with extra features like triggers to invalidate the next cache (revalidatePath), redirect to different path, and makes an obvious place to do form entry validation (with a library like zod), and makes it easy to do things like deploying loading state, error handling, optimistic updates, working with cookies.

I’m very curious to see if they extend server actions to be more generalizable past forms and data mutations. (yes, it is [possible](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions#invocation) and see discussion [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/54699))